# Moving average of a data series

Tags: python, numpy

How can I rework the code up that `ema(x, 5)` returns the data now in `emaout`? I'm trying to enclose everything in one def.

Right now its in a for loop and a def.

```
x = [32.47, 32.70, 32.77, 33.11, 33.25, 33.23, 33.23, 33.0, 33.04, 33.21]

def ema(series, period, prevma):
    smoothing = 2.0 / (period + 1.0)                
    return prevma + smoothing * (series[bar] - prevma)

prevema = x[0] 
emaout =[]

for bar, close in enumerate(x):
    curema = ema(x, 5, prevema) 
    prevema = curema
    emaout.append(curema)

print 
print emaout
```

`x` could be a NumPy array.

Answer (score 2):

1. ema uses series in one place, where it references `series[bar]`. But bar is a global variable which is frowned upon. Let's pass series[bar] instead of series to ema.
2. That would be series[bar] in the for loop, but series[bar] is the same thing as close, so let's pass that instead.
3. ema's period is only used to calculate smoothing. Let's calculate smoothing outside and pass it in.
4. But now ema's a single line, so let's inline it
5. Let's put all of that logic inside a function
6. We use enumerate in the for loop, but we don't use bar

Result:

```
x = [32.47, 32.70, 32.77, 33.11, 33.25, 33.23, 33.23, 33.0, 33.04, 33.21]

def function(x, period):
    prevema = x[0] 
    emaout =[]

    smoothing = 2.0 / (period + 1.0)                
    for close in x:
        curema = prevma + smoothing * (close - prevma) 
        prevema = curema
        emaout.append(curema)

    return prevema
print 
print function(x, 5)
```

We can better by using numpy.

```
def function(x, period):
    smoothing = 2.0 / (period + 1.0)                
    current = numpy.array(x) # take the current value as a numpy array

    previous = numpy.roll(x,1) # create a new array with all the values shifted forward
    previous[0] = x[0] # start with this exact value
    # roll will have moved the end into the beginning not what we want

    return previous + smoothing * (current - previous)
```

Comment: @ winston the answers dont match.

Comment: @Merlin, I didn't test what I wrote. But hopefully it gives you some idea of how to improve your existing code.

Comment: @merlin, `numpy.roll([1,2,3,4], 1) == numpy.array(4,1,2,3)` It shifts all of the elements in the array by one. That way when I subtract the original and rolled arrays I get the difference from one to the next.

Comment: @merlin, you are supposed to @ username of person you are talking to, not @ yourself. You don't need to when commenting on my questions because I am automatically alerted about those

Comment: @winston...the on numpy.roll, how can you 'roll' only one column in array? tIA

Comment: @Merlin, I've never needed to. Perhaps you should ask another question with the complete context of what you are now trying to accomplish.

Comment: The numpy version here doesn't implement the same algorithm and I don't think it's possible with the constructs shown. The problem is an EMA at index T is calculated based on the EMA at index T-1 (except for T=0 where the EMA must be hard-wired somehow). This explains the usage of the `prevema` value in the non-numpy example. Rolling the input values by 1 doesn't achieve this desired effect. Essentially EMA is a low-pass filter which I'm guessing can be implemented concisely using numpy/scipy, but I haven't found a good example yet.

Comment: @JoeHolloway, you are right. Apparently I was suffering from brain fog when I wrote this.